# PHP isset function

Tags: php

I believe I am a bit confused with the `isset` function in PHP. I'm trying to use this function to determine is a field in a form is `null`... I was under the impressions that the `isset` function checks to see if a field has a value in it... but I believe the `isset` function only determines if the thing passed to it exists.

For example.

If I have a form input field with the name attribute set to "day". I would use `isset($_GET['day']);` to determine if the form input field is not `null`? Or does `isset` just check to see if the 'day' exists and doesn't check that value that it passes?

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: `isset` is not a function, but a language construct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PHP `isset()` page:

> [isset() determines] if a variable is set and is not NULL.

This means that:

```
$var1;
$var2 = NULL;
$var3 = 0;
$var4 = 'test';
isset($var1); //false
isset($var2); //false
isset($var3); //true; note that if($var3) still returns false
isset($var4); //true
isset($var0); //false
```

To sum up that bit up there, `isset()` returns `FALSE` if the variable is either not set (hence the function name) or contains `NULL` as a value. For `isset()` to return true, a variable has to both exist and contain an actual value (boolean `false` included).

In your case with `$_GET['day']`, you can use `isset()` to check if a value has actually been passed to it (i.e., that it's not null).

Comment: Yes but if the input is empty, it will in fact pass a empty string `''`, so `isset` will return true, and you have to check with `empty`.

Comment: Good point. But as far as I'm aware, the default behaviour of empty fields is to not send a `$_GET` variable at all.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you're right. I personally use `empty` instead of `isset` since I often use Ajax and javascript to get values of input so I send it even if it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

Isset just check if a variable is defined. Use `empty` to know if it is null or undefined or something like that.

```
if(!empty($_GET['day']))
    //Stuff
```

Comment: Alright, so the isset function will always evaluate to false if you visit the form action seperately - for instance if I have the action in post.php and just typed the url to post.php in the browser it will evaluate to false. The only way it evaluates true is if the form is posted and the name value is set for the input field? Thanks for all the responses :)

Comment: Correct. However, don't use isset to check if your visitor come from your other page as anyone can do a fake form with the same input names that lead to your page post.php. But it prevent them for accessing the page directly, true.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely right, the isset() function just checks it the variable 'day' exists. In order to check if the value exist or is empty you have to use empty() function.